# Integrating Gradle with Jira

Tags: gradle, jira, build.gradle, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

Is there a way to integrate gradle with Jira ?

I use Jira cloud service and I know they have rest based API to support but I want to know weather there is a gradle plugin with good documentation to connect with Jira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Intershop Communications AG provides a plugin for dealing with JIRA from gradle. This might be what you're looking for https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/jiraconnector-gradle-plugin